# How can i sum two polynomials? in python

Tags: python

I have to make a program that can take from the user two polynomials (string) to calculate the result. The problem is that in polynomials the program must sum the coefficients that have the same power. I have to make it using class. I'm beginner in python. Thank you

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: please provide example of what is the expected i/p and o/p

Comment: SO isn't a place to get people do your homework -- you need to ask more specific questions and, if possible, show the code you have already written (the important parts of it).

Comment: it's not homework! I wanna learn how to use python using class.

Comment: @user1354396 OK, then you should just read this: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Also note that this sort of thing is already implemented in `numpy` ... If you're new to python, one of the best things about it is that somebody else has often already done the work ...

Answer (score 4):

Do you really want to parse the polynomials from strings? Because you can always represent polynomials as a list of coefficients for each of the terms. E.g.

```
[3 0 2 1]
```

would represent the polynomial

```
3 + 2*x^2 + x^3 == 0
```

Once you have that representation, summing the polynomials is trivial.

If you want to accept strings as input, you should first extract the coefficients from the string and build a coefficient vector, and then proceed.

**Edit:** Reversed the representation of the polynomial to make it more natural in the sense that element *i* represents the coefficient of *x^i*.

Comment: Adding polynomials would be much more trivial if the `i`-th element represented the coefficient for `x^i`.

Comment: @LevLevitsky `reversed()` ;). The representation he chose fits better the polynomial expression, the way it is usually written.

Comment: @jadkik94 You'd also have to use `reversed` to calculate the value of the polynomial at any value of `x` (or deal with index subtraction). To me, `sum(a*x^i for i, a in enumerate(p))` seems the most sound way.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I agree, but you could use `p = list(reversed(p))` once and for all... and it might be harder to parse the string into the format you proposed. But it's definitely better if you had it in this format.

Comment: Just to make it clear again: parsing the polynomial from a string representation is going to be *hard*. Unless, of course, you enforce it to be of a very specific format and you can enforce that format somehow.